# How to make containing window/frame expand to fit contents using tkinter grid?

Tags: python, tkinter

In the code below (copy and paste into text file and you should be able to run it immediately), text is entered into the Entry widget and then is displayed in the multicolumn list box. The columns of the list box expand to fit the text, but the containing window/frame does not expand to fit the expanded list box.

Try entering a short string, "test", and then a very long string "qwertyuiopasdf" to see what I mean.

How can it be made so that the containing window/frame expands to always fit the content? I would like to keep using the grid manager for organisation is possible.

The multicolumn list box is adapted from [here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/350266/creating-table-in-python) and the main application class is adapted from [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/minimal-app.html).

Python 3.5.1 on WIndows 10. Tkinter version 8.6.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

class McListBox(ttk.Treeview):
    #use a ttk.Treeview as a multicolumn ListBox
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        headers=kwargs['columns']
        id=kwargs['name']
        ttk.Treeview.__init__(self, master, name=id, columns=headers, show='headings')
        self.headers = headers
        self.items = []
        self.build_tree()

    def build_tree(self):
        # set up the columns
        for col in self.headers:
            self.heading(col, text=col.title())
            # adjust the column's width to the header string
            self.column(col, width=tkFont.Font().measure(col.title()))
        # in case items are added already
        for item in self.items:
            self.insert('', 'end', values=item)
            # adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value
            for ix, val in enumerate(item):
                col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
                if self.column(self.headers[ix],width=None)<col_w:
                    self.column(self.headers[ix], width=col_w)

    def add(self, text):
        # add the text in the first column and a 1 in the second
        item = (text, 1)
        self.insert('', 'end', values=item)
        # adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value
        for ix, val in enumerate(item):
            col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
            if self.column(self.headers[ix],width=None)<col_w:
                self.column(self.headers[ix], width=col_w)

class Application(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        # this is the multi column list box
        varDisplayArea = McListBox(self, name='varDisplayArea', columns=['var', 'val'])
        varDisplayArea.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')
        # this is the input to go into the multicolum list box
        inputBox = ttk.Entry(self, name='inputBox')
        inputBox.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W)
        inputBox.focus()
        self.master.bind('<Return>', self.addEntry)

    def addEntry(self, *args):
        # the value in the entry widget is added to the list box
        inputBox = self.children['inputBox']
        varDisplayArea = self.children['varDisplayArea']
        input = inputBox.get()
        inputBox.delete(0, END)
        varDisplayArea.add(input)
        inputBox.focus()

app = Application()
app.master.title('sample app')
app.mainloop()
```